# Can Sharepoint Online 2013's Custom List be able to export into Excel file without Sharepoint Foundation-compatible application?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

after researching for limited answers/solutions to this question. Is it possible that I'm able to export a Excel file without Sharepoint Foundation from Custom List using Sharepoint online 2013?
I have looked up that I must have my Internet Explorer to be 32-bit in order for me to avoid using Sharepoint Foundation. 
My issue is also that my organization is not able to download Sharepoint Foundation in the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use “export to excel” function, we need to run Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Support feature.

As a workaround, you can click “Quick Edit” in the List tab and copy the items in the list and paste them in the excel file.

Comment: If it helps, you can mark it as answer.